# spring data rest links to relations

Tags: rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, relation

I try to start with a simple spring data rest application and struggle around with multiple OneToMany relations. I have a person which has many items and many addresses. To get the application up and running I have to set the @RestResource annotation in items and address to create the correct links. But unfortunately the link doesn't work (I get an empty result) and why can't I set the @RestResource annotation in the person entity. Here is my code. I hope you can help me.

Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Item
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<Item> items;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Address
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Person() {
    }
// getter setter
```

Address

```
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String address;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Person
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    @RestResource(rel="address", path="address",exported=true)
    private Person person;

    public Address() {
    }

// getter setter
```

Item

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="items")
    public class Item implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        private int id;

        @Column(name="item_name")
        private String itemName;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to Person
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
        @RestResource(rel="item", path="item",exported=true)
        private Person person;

        public Item() {
        }
// getter setter
```

And I get this result

```
{
  "name" : "dave",
  "items" : [ {
    "itemName" : "ite,m"
  } ],
  "addresses" : [ {
    "address" : "myaddress1"
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/person/1"
    },
    "person" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/person/1"
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/person/1/address"
    },
    "item" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8090/person/1/item"
    }
  }
}%
```

Comment: Your output seems to be weird. Spring Data Rest inlines the association when there's no repository for given entity. When the repository is defined, the association is not inlined, but a link is provided. Can you post your repository interfaces?

Comment: Thanks a lot...works like a charm!